# Learning Ruby Caesar Cipher

Tags: ruby, caesar-cipher

I am trying to learn Ruby and made a simple Caesar cipher program and I was wondering if the following code follows the 'ruby way' or the way most ruby users would do it

```
# Implements the classes caesar cipher encryption and decryption.
class CaesarCipher
  def initialize(shift)
    @shift = shift
  end

  def encrypt(str)
    str_array = str.split("")
    str_array.map! { |char| round_over(char) }.join
  end

  def decrypt(str)
    str_array = str.split("")
    str_array.map! { |char| round_down(char) }.join
  end


  private
  def round_over(char)
    if char.ord + @shift > "z".ord
      (char.ord + @shift - 26).chr
    elsif char.ord + @shift > "Z".ord && char.ord <= "Z".ord
      (char.ord + @shift - 26).chr
    else
      (char.ord + @shift).chr
    end
  end

  def round_down(char)
    if char.ord - @shift < "a".ord && /[[:lower:]]/.match(char) # checks for lowercase
      (char.ord - @shift + 26).chr
    elsif char.ord - @shift < "A".ord
      (char.ord - @shift + 26).chr
    else
      (char.ord - @shift).chr
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

That's a pretty good start, however I noticed that your code only works on letters. For non-alphabetic characters it returns confusing results e.g. encrypting and decrypting `!` gives you `;`. I can think of three good ways to handle non-alphabetic characters:

- Ignore them
- Use ASCII codes to shift them as well (so `Z` shifted right one becomes `[`)
- Raise an error

Any of those approaches will ensure that decrypting and encrypting are inverses (which should be a property of any cipher!). That also leads you to a nice way to refactor your code: decrypting with a shift of 5 is the same thing as *encrypting* with a shift of -5. Try rewriting your code to look like this:

```
def encrypt(str)
  str.split('').map { |char| round(char, @shift) }.join
end

def decrypt(str)
  str.split('').map { |char| round(char, -@shift) }.join
end

private
def round(char, shift)
  # ...
end
```

Other than that, just a couple tips:

- Ways to compare ranges of characters: `/[a-z]/i =~ chr` or `(?A..?Z) === chr`
- What if `@shift` is greater than 26? You can use modulus `%` to account for shifts of any size

Answer (score 4):

Max already pointed out some good ways to improve the actual character shifting (definitely use `%`!). I'll offer some low-level advice

- There's no reason to use the "bang" (`!`) version of `map`; just use the regular non-bang version
- Use `String#chars` instead of `split`
- You can since you pass the block parameter for `map` directly on to your `round_*` methods, you could just use `map(&method(:round_down))...`
- And you can in fact write it all as a chain

  ```
  def encrypt(str)
    str.chars.map(&method(:round_over)).join
  end
  ```

  and similar for `decrypt`
- `round_over` should be called `round_up` - it's normal English, and it's the more appropriate "opposite" of `round_down`. Eitherway, both those methods should probably be renamed `shift_*` or `rotate_*`, since they're not really *rounding* anything; they're shifting or rotating the characters
- Don't use `match` in a conditional when you just want a boolean; use Ruby's `=~` operator to check a string against a regex: `char =~ /[[:lower:]]/`. `match` is better suited for when you want to pull matched parts out of a string; not when you just want a true/false
- You can use `?A` and `?z` etc. instead of `"A".ord` (just a handy shortcut/alternative syntax). Max also used this in a range expression.
- Again: Take Max's advice and rewrite the private methods. But eitherway, you should at least calculate `char.ord +/- @shift` *once*, and then do the `if..elsif..else` branching. Don't calculate it for every conditional *and* again for output.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you suspect that the problem you are tackling is rather common, Ruby probably has a method for it. In many cases you will be able to guess it's name - admittedly not in this case.

Ruby strings have an easily overlooked method named [tr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-tr) which replaces characters of a string with specified other characters. This specification is done on initialize, after which the actual en- and de-crypting is trivial.

```
class CaesarCipher
  ALFABET = ("a".."z").to_a 
  CHARS = "a-zA-Z"

  def initialize(shift)
    lkey = ALFABET.rotate(shift).join
    @key = lkey + lkey.upcase
  end

  def encrypt(str)
    str.tr(CHARS, @key)
  end

  def decrypt(str)
    str.tr(@key, CHARS)
  end
end
```

Comment: Great answer, but that kind of sucks the fun out of writing a cipher.